# Can this SQL query be made to run any faster?

Tags: mysql

I'm using mySQL InnoDB tables. The query is simple but it just takes too long to run. Its bound to run even slower once I upload it to a server (not to mention that these two tables will keep growing in size).

The 'author' table size is 3,045 records.
The 'book' table size is 5,278 records.

```
SELECT author.*, count( auth_id ) AS author_count
FROM author
LEFT JOIN book ON author.id = book.auth_id
GROUP BY author.id
```

I'm wondering if there is some trick I can employ to make the query run *at least* twice as fast as it is now (it currently takes about 10.5 seconds to run - an eternity when displaying web content!)

Comment: stupid question, but have you indexed the book.auth_id?

Comment: Can you add the output of `EXPLAIN <YOUR QUERY>`? That way we can see how MySQL executes your query. Also, you should fix your `GROUP BY` to include all non-aggregate (i.e. everything except `max`/`min`/`count`/etc..) columns.

Comment: Tough to say without seeing your table structure. Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and see where a bottleneck may be. But your rows count don't worry me.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all - as a matter of fact, that was the answer.  I've been moving tables around a lot between databases and for one reason or another, I had lost my index on book.auth_id.

Sorry to all who took the time to help me - I should have noticed the missing index instead of wasting all your time.

BTW: For the record, having re-established my index, the query now runs in 0.03 seconds - now THAT I can live with.

Thanks again to all who helped me!!

Answer (score 0):

1) Is this returning what you want?

2) You should list in the GROUP BY clause all the fields from the SELECT clause that are not in an agregate function (like COUNT in this case, but also could be AVG or SUM).

Comment: MySQL does not require all non-aggregate columns to be included in the GROUP BY and will choose a random row to supply the other column values.  In this particular case, that's okay because presumably "author" will contribute only a single row to each group.

Comment: That's why I purposefully did not include the other table columns in the GROUP BY - I know that you normally should but I got away with not doing it.